# TFS 2012 Process Template - Column Updates not Displaying for Product and Iteration Backlogs -

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I've update the AgileConfiguration.xml process template to include specific columns, column order and widths to match how our teams work.  After importing the process configuration, I was expecting the changes to be reflected in Web Access product and iteration backlog pages.  The changes do not appear, rather I see my personal column changes I may have made over time.  I've tested in a new Team Project, the changes appear.

How can I remove my personal modifications and test to ensure the changes are applied?  Further, how can I ensure all users receive the updates if they have made their own changes?

Example of the template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<AgileProjectConfiguration>
  <IterationBacklog>
    <Columns>
      <Column width="65" refname="System.WorkItemType" />
      <Column width="400" refname="System.Title" />
      <Column width="60" refname="System.State" />
      <Column width="45" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork" />
      <Column width="90" refname="System.AssignedTo" />
      <Column width="40" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority" />
      <Column width="100" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Triage" />
      <Column width="50" refname="Custom.SCRID" />
      <Column width="250" refname="System.AreaPath" />
    </Columns>
  </IterationBacklog>
  <ProductBacklog>
    <AddPanel>
      <Fields>
        <Field refname="System.Title" />
      </Fields>
    </AddPanel>
    <Columns>
      <Column width="65" refname="System.WorkItemType" />
      <Column width="400" refname="System.Title" />
      <Column width="60" refname="System.State" />
      <Column width="45" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.Effort" />
      <Column width="90" refname="System.AssignedTo" />
      <Column width="100" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Triage" />
      <Column width="150" refname="System.IterationPath" />
      <Column width="50" refname="Custom.SCRID" />
      <Column width="50" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.BacklogPriority" />
      <Column width="250" refname="System.AreaPath" />
    </Columns>
  </ProductBacklog>
</AgileProjectConfiguration>
```